# Paypal return dynamic link?

Tags: php, paypal

I have a site and need to set up a return link for paypal.

The problem is that I have the return link dynamic where the user id changes based on who is logged in.

```
http://my-site.com/user/3/billing/done    // number 3 changes
```

Any advice on this?

I'm talking about the return URL that is at my paypal account setting. Not the button form...

Comment: i wouldn't put the id in the link you can parse variables to pp who will then return them via IPN

Comment: You really need to give some more information.  Is this in a paypal button?

Comment: if I won't use it. It will not land on the proper page

Comment: @quid, no, I'm trying to add the link in my paypal settings

Comment: Obviously an account setting at paypal is a static value.  If you want a dynamic value you'll have to pass the value with each transaction.

Comment: How is the transaction being initiated?

Answer (score 0):

To use a dynamic return link you'll need to pass your return URL with each transaction, just echo the id into the return input.  "return" is the post value that paypal uses to return a buyer to your site after a transaction.

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://mysite.net/user/<?php echo $userid; ?>/billing/done">
```

Comment: I have this set up but I need to set up automatic redirection in paypal account

Comment: to automatically reditrect you need to turn on the automatic re-direct in your PayPAl account.